# IE page-breaking issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In Google Chrome (And I think firefox?) a page renders correctly

But in IE, the page appears to be "transparent", see [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMBCU.jpg).

```
<div style="margin-left:-10px;float:left;width:130px;height:30px; background-image:url('/gc_mycoinamount_display.png');">
<div id="mygoldamount" style="margin-top:7px;">5 Coins</div>
```

I believe this div causes the issue, when I remove it, the page looks correct. Is the CSS on it incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to close a div, silly me.

```
<div style="margin-left:-10px;float:left;width:130px;height:30px; background-image:url('/gc_mycoinamount_display.png');">
<div id="mygoldamount" style="margin-top:7px;">5 Coins</div></div>
```